# how to change a variable after opening window dialog in vbscript?

Tags: pointers, vbscript

I have 2 buttons, 1st and 2nd. If the 1st button is clicked it will open a dialog box that contains a textbox. The text that is inserted in the textbox is stored in the variable `text1`.

My question is how to change the variable `text1` to `text2` if I clicked the 2nd button? (If the 2nd button is clicked it will open the same dialog box as when the 1st button is clicked)

Comment: Can you show the code you already have because this doesn’t sound like VBScript but more likely VBA which while similar has significant differences.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable to hold the content of both `text1` and `text2`.

```
Dim sText

Sub Button1_Click()
    sText = InputBox("Enter value:", "Button 1", sText)
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()
    sText = InputBox("Enter value:", "Button 2", sText)
End Sub
```

To make this more general, you can create a `Sub` to show the dialog (in this example I am using [InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function)):

```
Dim sText

Sub ShowDialog()
    sText = InputBox("Enter value:", "Button Click", sText)
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click()
    ShowDialog
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()
    ShowDialog
End Sub
```

You can read about variable scope in this article: [Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications). This applies to VBScript also.

Comment: Think you might be “jumping the gun” a bit here, without any code in the question it’s difficult to assume they are talking about VBScript. Wouldn’t recommend answering questions until it is clear what the OP is trying to do and at least shows some sort of attempt to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: I agree that I don't have much to go on but variable scope is probably going to go a long way towards what the gist of the question is about I feel. The implementation of the dialog itself is not relevant to the variable scope. I do appreciate your comment though and I do make assumptions I probably shouldn't. I enjoy SO for the diligence users like you bring to these questions and answers.